# Why I can't place text in parallelogram with one side

Tags: html, css

I have span, i created parallelogram with one side, but my text is not inside area of span, do you know what is problem?

also i try t osolve this problem adding display:block, but not working
http://jsfiddle.net/46be3tL4/5/

HTML

```
<span>LOREM IPSUM DOLOR</span>
```

CSS

```
span {
    display:block;
    border-top: 100px solid red;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    height: 0;
    width: 100px;

}
```

Comment: Because you added a border, not a background.

Comment: mate that's not solution

Comment: @RS92 Comments need not necessarily be solutions. And Oriol's comment is a good point to ponder about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You added a border, not a background.

You can:

- Add the border to a pseudo-element instead of to the element itself
- Use absolute positioning to remove the pseudo-element from the normal flow of the document, and thus make it overlap the content.
- Use a negative z-index to place the pseudo-element under the content.

```css
span {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  min-height: 40px;
}
span:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  border-top: 40px solid red;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<span>LOREM IPSUM DOLOR</span>
```

Comment: Ok that's it, thank you for end, can you tell me how to center text inside div vertically, i added padding-top:10px; but not working, can I set universal height, using padding?

Comment: @RS92 If there will only be one line of text, you can use `line-height: 40px`.

Comment: Is it possible to set auto widht depend of width text contents, and to set padding:10px;

Comment: @Oriol sorry, but when I implemented your code in my project I have problem ,because i have one picture, and over her I want to place this parallelogram, here is code, I can't to display text on paralelogram.
http://jsfiddle.net/wqhtpxng/1/

Comment: @RS92 OK, the `span` needed some `z-index` in order to create a stacking context: http://jsfiddle.net/wqhtpxng/2/